# Combine two files with unequal length on common column with multiple matches with linux command line

Tags: sql, linux, bash, join, awk

I know some similar questions had been ask, but I struggle to get awk, join or anything else to do what I want.

I have to tab delimited files.

File 1:

```
Text1 Text2 Text3

1000 128 128/D59

1001 116 116/A95
```

Every row is unique and every element in the first column occurs only once.

File 2:

```
Text1 Text4 Text5 Text6

1000 1003 19901001 1

1000 1002 19901001 2

1001 1003 19971005 0
```

Every row is unique but any element can occur multiple times in the file. The both files have obviously different numbers of rowns and columns.

My desired file3:

```
Text1 Text4 Text5 Text6 Text2 Text3

1000 1003 19901001 1 128 128/D59

1000 1002 19901001 2 128 128/D59

1001 1003 19971005 0 116 116/A95
```

The order of columns isn't actually important. The real file1 has 18024188 lines and the real file2 has 89122313 lines.
All that I did so far with join or awk did not produce a row like the second one in the example. I do not really care about using this two programms, any solution will fit. If it would be easier (and someone explains me how to do it) I could also transform this into a sql db and try to join them (I am trying a full outer join, right?).

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify something: If you want all records that are present in `file2` that may or may not be `file1` then it would be left outer join on `file2`. IF you want all records which are in both files then it will be full outer join and respective fields will be empty which are not present. What do you want ?

Comment: Well that is a good question: There should be no record in file2 that does not have a corresponding record in file1. So both joins should lead to the same result. However, if my data is corrupted I most likely want to know that. So I guess I want a left outer join and will fill with NA or correct any row with less than 6 columns. Edit: I hope I am clear.

Comment: :So you basically need `Inner Join`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: wc -l file3. Gives just 64975775 lines. So 24146538 lines gone missing. Apparently I have some date issues. So I seem to need a left outer join as starting point where to find the problem. Edit: Haven't seen batMan's answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **awk**

**Left Outer Join** on **file2**

```
$ awk  'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2FS$3; next} ($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]; next} {print $0,"NA","NA"}' file1 file2

Text1 Text4 Text5 Text6 Text2 Text3

1000 1003 19901001 1 128 128/D59

1000 1002 19901001 2 128 128/D59

1001 1003 19971005 0 116 116/A95

2000 1003 19971005 0 NA  NA
```

`FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2FS$3; next}` : To store contents of `file1` in associative array `a` where the key is unique field one

`($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]}`: While iterating over `file2` check if the first field/key exists in the array. If yes print its value alongside the record.

If key doesn't exist in array (For eg. `2000`) then just print the record which is in `file2`; this will reflect the behaviour of `left outer join` on `file2`.

**Inner Join** on both files :

```
$ awk  'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2FS$3; next} ($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]}' file1 file2
Text1 Text4 Text5 Text6 Text2 Text3

1000 1003 19901001 1 128 128/D59

1000 1002 19901001 2 128 128/D59

1001 1003 19971005 0 116 116/A95
```

Comment: Thank you. The result looks like that I want to get.

Comment: @NicDoe I've updated my commands for Outer as well as inner join. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you again. Now the number of rows fits and I see NA were the data is broken. Left outer join on file2 did the trick.