# full outer join with awk

Tags: join, awk, outer-join

After reading:

[Combine two files with unequal length on common column with multiple matches with linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807640/combine-two-files-with-unequal-length-on-common-column-with-multiple-matches-wit)

I wonder how you would do a full outer join.
(hopefully it's ok to start a new question with it)

file one

```
A 1 
C 4
```

file two

```
A 2 
B 5
```

file three

```
A 7 
D 9
```

the result would be:

```
A 1    2   7 
B N    5   N 
C 4    N   N 
D N    N   9
```

Is there an `awk`-one-line-solution like I saw for left outer join?

Comment: Hi. You are trying to do something involving multiple joins, but it's not immediately clear what, so please edit to be clear. An outer join takes two tables & returns one. Where are your column headings? What have you been able to do? What do you understand full join to return in terms of left & right join? Please read & act on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Don't use a link for things essential to your question, edit everthing that an answer needs directly into your question.

Comment: Don't ask for "one line" solutions as that tells everyone you care more about brevity than all the things that actually matter in software such as clarity, efficiency, portability, robustness, etc. so it can make people reluctant to provide a good solution as you might reject it in favor of some crappy, brief alternative. Any software can be squeezed onto one line if that's important to you for some reason, and any software can also be stored in a file and then that file executed as one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays, ARGIND, and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ vals[$1][ARGIND] = $2 }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (key in vals) {
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
            val = (fileNr in vals[key] ? vals[key][fileNr] : "N")
            printf "%s%s", val, (fileNr<ARGIND ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
A 1 2 7
B N 5 N
C 4 N N
D N N 9
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to solve this using the POSIX-standard `join` command. Given that the three files proposed in the question are named `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`:

```
join -a1 -a2 -eN -o 0,1.2,2.2 1.txt 2.txt | join -a1 -a2 -eN -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 - 3.txt
```

Note that while this provides the required output for the question as stated, it's quite a bit less flexible than Ed Morton's `awk`-based solution. For one thing, `join` needs its input files to be sorted on the shared field(s). And for another, it will only work for exactly three input files.

However, it's possibly simpler to use `join` in once-off ad hoc cases!